# Does voting up too many posts from a single user trigger an automatic undo of those votes?

Tags: support, up-votes

I thought suspicious voting patterns were just noted in the mod's "Suspicious voting patterns" list and it was up to them to determine if the votes should be undone.  Is there more to it than this?  If the voting pattern reaches a certain threshold, will the votes be undone automatically?

The reason I ask is because Fog Creek has created a [FogBugz FAQ](http://fogbugz.stackexchange.com/users/68/fogbugz-faq) user on http://fogbugz.stackexchange.com to post documentation.  I have recently voted on many of this user's posts only to see all those votes disappear.

Comment: Can I ask why you asked? We had a LOT of similar questions in the last few days all of a sudden.

Comment: @Kop: I can't think of a better way to explain why I asked than the second paragraph of my question.  That FogBugz FAQ user cries out to be "serial upvoted" because of all the good information they post with that account.  Now I know I can't do that.  I guess I'll have to spread my votes out over time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know exactly how it works - and most other people here won't either.

But check out these links here:

- [Vote Fraud and You](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/vote-fraud-and-you/)
- [More Voting Anomalies](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/more-voting-anomalies/)
- [How does the SO voter fraud detection mechanism work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19920/how-does-the-so-voter-fraud-detection-mechanism-work)

It is definitely possible that if you went round and gave a load of up votes in very quick succession your votes may have been removed.

Comment: There is nothing more to add except that it check every 24 hours.

Comment: Ah yes, i should have mentioned that it is a daily script. Thanks

Comment: I'd say that Vote Fraud and You article answers my question, "...we now use several daily heuristics to detect strange user upvoting patterns; if we decide the upvotes are questionable, they will *all* be removed."