# Coworker upvoted a lot of my posts, I lost reputation

Tags: support, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the SO voter fraud detection mechanism work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19920/how-does-the-so-voter-fraud-detection-mechanism-work)
>   [Does voting up too many posts from a single user trigger an automatic undo of those votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63902/does-voting-up-too-many-posts-from-a-single-user-trigger-an-automatic-undo-of-th)

A guy at my work upvoted a bunch of my StackOverflow answers/questions yesterday, which was pretty neat. I guess he was just reading through them and upvoted the ones he liked.

Today all the votes were deleted and I might have even lost some additional rep. Did he trigger some kind of safety mechanism and then cause a recalc on my account?

I'm just curious if this is actually against the rules, or if it looked like abuse. I could see that and it's no big deal. Although, for the record, christmas is ruined.

Comment: Yeah, he tripped the suspicious voting activity algorithm. Nice touch mentioning Christmas though, it's kind of a big deal around here.

Comment: Wow, [How does the SO voter fraud detection mechanism work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19920/how-does-the-so-voter-fraud-detection-mechanism-work) is bad FAQ post. I guess [Does voting up too many posts from a single user trigger an automatic undo of those votes?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63902/does-voting-up-too-many-posts-from-a-single-user-trigger-an-automatic-undo-of-th) better answers it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

His votes were invalidated by the vote fraud script.

Note that this script issues an automatic reputation recalc after the votes are invalidated, so you might lose some additional rep for deleted posts. Don't worry, the rep that you "lost" wasn't real anyways.

Tell him not to do it again, as this might even get *you* in trouble. It's not against the rules to have accounts from the same IP, but if his account exists for the sole purpose of upvoting your posts (or it looks that way), there's no way for us to tell that he isn't just a sockpuppet.

#### See:

- [Vote Fraud and You](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/vote-fraud-and-you/)
- [More Voting Anomalies](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/more-voting-anomalies/)

Comment: How is that going to scale? A big organisation might have only a single external IP for their entire site. Do you assume everyone at Google/Microsoft/Facebook are sockpuppets?