# Loss of Votes count on StackOverflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, stack-exchange, users, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the SO voter fraud detection mechanism work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19920/how-does-the-so-voter-fraud-detection-mechanism-work)

In stackoverflow, when in a day i get huge number of votes from a single user then the votes are automatically rolled back the next day. Is it an automatic system that if number of votes from a single user goes high then all the votes are stripped off, or is there a moderator for this?

Comment: Something like that, yes : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19920/how-does-the-so-voter-fraud-detection-mechanism-work

Comment: Okay, so who is http://stackoverflow.com/users/782296/abhimanyu-srivastava and why shouldn't we consider him a sockpuppet and merge your two accounts?

Comment: He is a developer friend of mine and that's not my account.

Answer (score 0):

This happens via an automated system, our moderators will only clear votes in the case of sock puppeting type situations, where a large portion of votes were earned illegitimately.