# Incorrect display of reputation points on StackOverflow?

Tags: support, reputation, voting

On [my profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/768894/mohit) my reputation points are being displayed as 364 but when I checked my overall reputation on stack exchange [my overall reputation on stack exchange](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow/2011-09-25/768894?sort=reputationchange#768894) it was showing 495.
Also on my StackOverflow profile I am awarded Mortarboard badge.But I have never earned 200 rep points in a single day.
What is going on ? Is my account hacked or something ?

Comment: What does [your Reputation page](http://www.stackoverflow.com) say?

Comment: my reputation points are changing automatically.

Answer (score 3):

There were some statistical anomalies in the voting to your account.

These anomalies were removed.

Comment: what kind of anomalies ?Now my rep has become 280.Just few seconds ago it was 464.

Comment: @mohit: [Oh, you know...stuff that shouldn't happen.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19920/how-does-the-so-voter-fraud-detection-mechanism-work)

Comment: @Padded The reputation points I have earned even 3 months back are gone now.

Comment: @mohit: Okay, let me try to explain that for you. The Uber-Boss (Jeff here) used the Uber-Script (Vote-Fraud-Detection) and has found that most of your reputation was obtained via fraud. You either did that on purpose (sockpuppet accounts) or on...well, purpose, with the help of a friend ("Vote all my stuff up"). If you think this is in error, then I suggest that you tell us that.

Comment: @padded it can happen accidentally if friends try to be "friendly" and vote up all your content. Note: this will not end well.

Comment: @JeffAtwood I can see a diff today on my reputation too. It was 35 more than what I can see it now last night. Also, the last reputation that I gained was 35 for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41024376/maven-clean-excluding-directory-inside-target-from-being-deleted/41024994#41024994