# incorrect calculation of the reputation points

Tags: support, reputation

I have found [difference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107802/incorrect-display-of-reputation-points-on-stackoverflow) betweens my [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/714968/mkorbel?tab=reputation) on SO in amount 105

[image]

and with popup window that displayed wrong calculations for same amounts in 115, there is difference +10

[image]

EDIT 1:

how many times my mother told me `"never trust a foreign people"`

[image]

I did trigger a rep recalc... there are some difference, what's problem, from where came these shadows points,

Comment: Out of curiosity what does http://stackoverflow.com/reputation say? Also did you trigger a rep recalc?

Comment: I wonder if SO has cached the results of the query to get your profile popup.

Comment: Eventual consistency! (even though SO's run from a single box afaik)

Comment: please see my Edit :-)

Comment: @mKorbel please see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep in mind if a question is removed by a moderator, that you had answered, or your answer is removed by a moderator, you lose any rep gains associated with that upvote, or edit.

Comment: Not immediately. You have to recalculate reputation for the it to be adjusted.

Comment: look like as done, +1

Comment: Was just something I noticed, I do try to edit and answer some bad questions, and noticed a rep loss myself later, or conflicting rep numbers in my tracker and signature.

Answer (score 3):

## CACHING CACHING CACHING.

That is **usually** the culprit.

Comment: only one up-vote +1