# Is this acceptable user interaction?

Tags: discussion, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there some mechanism for preventing a two-person team from farming rep?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111574/is-there-some-mechanism-for-preventing-a-two-person-team-from-farming-rep)

Yesterday, I ran across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366220/add-child-gridview-in-parent-gridview-and-raise-the-event-of-child), which I downvoted and flagged. I then went back to the review interface, browsed around for a while, and later checked back in on the question, where I was stunned to see that someone had actually answered it with a concrete amount of code.

I've seen people answer (or attempt to answer) extremely obtuse questions before, but the preciseness of code posted here and lack of any text asking for clarification raised my eyebrows, so I immediately wondered if the person who answered the question was a sock puppet of the person who asked it (for reference: [poster's profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1070666/gk-ranjan), [answerer's profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1070785/pradip-shukla).

On further review, I'm not entirely convinced that's the case. However, looking at both users' SO profiles, they **at least** work at the same company. I've never seen an instance like this before, although I'm sure it's come up (perhaps not quite to this degree). So, my question is: assuming that these users are actually two distinct people, is this a case of two people gaming the system, or is it acceptable for two users who have a working relationship to use StackOverflow as a way to answer each other's questions?

---

Edit: I notice now that the original question has been removed.

Comment: I see an awful lot of one asking an almost-entirely-nonsensical question and the other answering, usually the only answer and accepted as well. This is certainly something a mod should be looking into.

Comment: Yeah. I should've mentioned: the poster answered his/her own questions a few times before the answerer starts answering/asking. This makes me wonder if the poster thought he/she could garner rep by answering his/her own posts, and then realized it would take another person to pull this off. But, perhaps I've been watching too many crime dramas lately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The post you linked to is definitely low-quality enough to just delete.  The linked activity between the two users is suspicious, but there's not really enough voting activity on either account to be sure if it's sock puppetry or just two co-workers as you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation -- I figured that there wasn't enough of a history between the two users to classify the behavior as abusive, but I'd rather have mods make decisions about moderation. :)