# Is mass-accepting answers from the same user to drive up rep acceptable?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, spam, ethics

Similar questions have been asked, for instance: [Is there some mechanism for preventing a two-person team from farming rep?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111574/251391)

This situation, however, is a little different: I ran [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/6607/the-true-unsung-heros) for "true unsung heroes" and found that [the top user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4679402/vipswelt) has all of his accepted answers from the same user... and all within just a few minutes.

I suppose this would not be an issue if the answers were all of good quality, but in this case that is certainly not true.

I know that there are measures in place to prevent serial (up-)voting, but are there also mechanisms for accepting answers? If not, is this acceptable behavior or should something be done about it?

---

**Edit:**
As mentioned in the comments, this particular account could be a sockpuppet account used for cheating, or just a friend who got a warm welcome from another friend. How do we reconcile the two? The former is certainly grounds for account suspension or deletion, but the latter should probably just be dealt with on the merit of each answer.

Is this just one of those things that needs to be dealt with on a case to case basis?

Comment: Look like it could be sock puppet account... At some point he may make a bounty transfer between them.

Comment: "serial accepting reversed" is something I would like to see. ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard In case of a sock puppet you likely won't, it'll be simply deleted entirely

Comment: @Mad true, but my feeling is that it's "just" a real life friend of the OP who arrived at SO and got a warm welcome from him.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the two users know each other, no it is not acceptable behavior. This is a form of coordinated voting, which is why I warned both users about this at the time.

The system cleaned up most of the voting here, and I removed many of the posts involved, but the system missed some of the votes. After seeing that, I decided not to bother an SE employee to invalidate the rest, pending further actions of these users. If they take my warning to heart, I'll let them be. If not, more serious action will be called for.

There are times where this is purely coincidence, but those tend to be the minority of cases. Generally, I've observed that if one user exists solely to accept the answers of another, they tend to be somehow connected.

Answer (score 4):

> are there also mechanisms for accepting answers?

I can't give a definitive answer on that, since I don't know and don't have the means to check.

So what remains is:

> is this acceptable behavior or should something be done about it?

Usually, the system does its work very well. If a bad question or a bad answer is posted, the community will usually vote based on the quality, and all reputation gained from getting his answer accepting will get lost. Also, he will get closer to a post ban and the system will reverse all suspicious reputation.

In this case though, the system worked a little, since [a lot of the up-votes where reversed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4679402/vipswelt?tab=reputation), but the accepts didn't. Since both users work in the same company, it seems to me they are actual friends, and posting just to accept and up-vote the answer of your friend is not according to the rules.

So no, it isn't acceptable. And yes, something should be done against this (maybe they have been handed out a temporary ban already). Probably those accepts should be reversed too as part of the voting fraud.