# Reputation dropped by 700 points?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

I logged on to SO today to see a 700 point drop in my reputation. It used to be 1918 and now it's 1213. I can't figure out where things changed, and all the "official" calculations don't give me any idea what went wrong. I wasn't getting tons of points from any particular post, so I'm pretty sure its unrelated to someone deleting something. I haven't paid much attention to it, and I know there's a "background function" that checks for specifics, but I haven't done much of anything in the past few days.

Anyone have ideas?

Comment: You triggered a reputation recalc from your [reputation audit](http://stackoverflow.com/reputation) page today, according to the event logs.

Comment: Look at your reputation audit in detail, and see if you can find anything that would explain it. I can't get to your reputation audit page, and the reputation tab in your profile does not show deleted posts (by design).

Comment: I only triggered the audit AFTER I lost the 700 points, to see if they came back. I've been looking and I never paid much attention to the details of my reputation before so I'm not sure what's missing. I had no idea that there were recalcs.

Comment: Perhaps an over enthusiastic fan of yours triggered the [fraud detection mechanism](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19920/how-does-the-so-voter-fraud-detection-mechanism-work) and a bunch of their votes were nullified?

Comment: Google [web cache of your profile](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:rYH_uEgZXAMJ:stackoverflow.com/users/334934/mishiemoo+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) shows you at 1198 on November 7th.

Comment: Perhaps an account merge?

Answer (score 4):

Based on the information so far I can't think of any other reason, so I'm going to stick my neck out and post my comments above as an answer.

> Perhaps an over enthusiastic fan of yours triggered the [fraud detection mechanism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19920/how-does-the-so-voter-fraud-detection-mechanism-work) and a bunch of their votes were nullified

As Rick Sladkey has pointed out, [the google cache of your profile](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:rYH_uEgZXAMJ:stackoverflow.com/users/334934/mishiemoo%20&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) puts you at 1198 on the 7th of November. You've only posted one question and one answer (on your question) since then with one upvote each, so it is plausible that the 700+ reps stem from an overzealous fan/supporter.

Comment: At 10 rep per answer upvote, that's over 70 upvotes, which exceeds two full days worth of votes. Unless the OP has an entire entourage of overzealous fans, I doubt this is the answer (or, at least, the entire answer).

Comment: 70 upvotes over 11 days isn't that hard to do, even for a single voter. Of course, I'm not discounting the fact that there may be more to it than this.

Comment: My point was that it'd be strange for the system to not detect the fraud for the first few days, only to pick it up today. Not impossible, just strange. But of course this is all hypothetical.

Comment: Ahh.. ok, I get ya.